# Python - global variable inside a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, variables, while-loop, global

I have this code, where:
last_price - is a variable that gets data from a price feed.

the code, does not work as intended. it shows this output "2 test line Y", but it should show 'test line success Y'

EDIT: I cannot use "continue", because last_price is changing every second, and (Y = 'test line Y') will become (Y = 'some other command') and the code will continue execute order_succeeded_1 indefinitely.

How can I fix this code?

```
last_price = 230
SL = 100
SL1 = 200
SL2 = 300
SL3 = 400

X = 'yes X'
Y = 'yes Y'
Z = 'yes Z'

def addvar (A, B):
    while True:
        global X, Y, Z
        if X == 'test line X':
            print ('test line success X')
            break
        if Y == 'test line Y':
            print ('test line success Y')
            break  
        if Z == 'test line Z':
            print ('test line success Z')
            break  
        
        if SL < last_price <= SL1 : # 100 --- 200
            order_succeeded = A+B   # 10
            X = 'test line X'       
            print (order_succeeded, X)
            break
          
    
        if SL1 < last_price <= SL2 : # 200 --- 300
            order_succeeded_1 = A-B  # 2
            Y = 'test line Y'          
            print (order_succeeded_1, Y)          
            break

        if SL2 < last_price <= SL3 :    # 300 --- 400
            Z = 'test line Z'        
            order_succeeded_2 = A * B   # 24          
            print (order_succeeded_2, Z)
            break

addvar (6, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `continue` instead of `break` here, when you use break you get out of your while and `Y == 'test line Y'` is not executed for the second time:

```
if SL1 < last_price <= SL2:  # 200 --- 300
    order_succeeded_1 = A - B  # 2
    Y = 'test line Y'
    print(order_succeeded_1, Y)
    continue
```

Comment: that worked, but only if the last_price is static. In my case, last_price is changing every second, and (Y = 'test line Y') will become (Y = 'some other command') and the code will continue execute order_succeeded_1 indefinitely.

Comment: How do you change your last_price variable?

Comment: last_price is updated via API feed, but in terms of this test code, I just type a different number manually

Comment: Do you use continue for all last_price comparisons? SL < last_price <= SL1, SL1 < last_price <= SL2 etc

Comment: yes, used "continue" for other price comparisons too, the loop stuck on Y